# How can I wrap text to some length in Vim?

Tags: vim, indentation

Let's speak of relative measures. My Vim looks like:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaa 
bbbbbbbbbbbbb 
ccccccccccccc 
etc
```

I would like it to be smaller:

```
aaaaa
aaaaa
bbbbb
bbbbb
ccccc
ccccc
etc
```

How can I get it? And how can I manage setting the length of such a block?

Comment: Do you mean wrap text, and not indent text?

Comment: lc: I do not know the difference. I was going to write wrap as it was recommended to me, but I have never got it working.

Answer (score 209, accepted):

You can actually do two things:

1. Let vim format (i.e.change) your text to have shorter lines, by inserting linebreaks
2. Leave lines as they are, but *display* them wrapped

Which do you want?

Option 1 would be achieved by setting `textwidth` (for example `:set textwidth=30` (from Swaarop's answer)). Then you can reformat your text by highlighting it (in visual mode) and typing `gq`. (`textwidth` can be abbreviated as `tw`, thus `:set tw=30`.)

Option 2 can be toggled by running `:set wrap` / `:set nowrap`. This will wrap lines which are too long for the window.

Both are independent.

Comment: +1 for the gq key command from visual mode, thats awsomely useful

Comment: FYI this breaks on spaces and gqgq doesn't do anything to a line like shown in the question even if tw=5.

Comment: @Dlamblin: Correct. If you want to fold at exactly the given width,  without respecting whitespace, then use the `fold` command as in fgm's answer.

Comment: Your option to does not work as far as I see. `wrap` will wrap at the window boundary, not at `textwidth`.

Comment: @DerWeh: Yes, wrap will wrap at the window boundary. I edited to clarify.

Comment: How to set the window boundary within vim without changing the terminal size?

Comment: Another vim learning lesson! Instead of setting `tw`, I set `formatprg=fmt\ -70\ -s` and use gq on visual mode and it's perfect! I can now format those git commit messages. Don't forget to escape the spaces in formatprg.

Answer (score 73):

Once you set 'textwidth', you can select text with visual mode and press gq to wrap it nicely (you can also use Q on some older/legacy configurations).

A few useful tips:

```
gqq (wrap the current line)
gq} (wrap this 'paragraph', i.e. until the next blank line)
:h gq
```

Comment: +1, I accidentally hit gq while in vim, have spent the last half hour trying to see what it was I hit. This is so useful.

Comment: `gqq` also wraps the current line (instead of `gqgq` or `gq$`).

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me when you have existing text that needs wrapping. The other answers set a configuration rather than force wrapping existing text.

Comment: see also `gw`. I often prefer this to `gq`, since it leaves your cursor in the same place after formatting (see `:h gw`).  I habitually type `gwip` to format the paragraph I'm currently editing without moving the cursor.

Answer (score 25):

Using fold(1) is one possibility:

```
:%!fold -w5
```

Result:

```
aaaaa
aaaaa
aaa 
bbbbb
bbbbb
bbb 
ccccc
ccccc
ccc
```

Comment: This also doesn't respect spaces for folding

Comment: @Lionel: Yes. To respect spaces, add option "-s" to the fold command.

Answer (score 14):

```
:set textwidth=30
```

Comment: How does textwidth handle it when there are no spaces, like in the original poster's example? I've had a play and it only seems to format based on textwidth if there are spaces (or assumedly, if the breakat variable is set to something else).

Comment: @Andy `textwidth` will not handle a no-spaces situation. You can write your own `formatexpr` function to do that.

Answer (score 8):

If you have text without spaces that you want to break at a certain length, it is neither necessary to use external `fold` nor write your own `formatexpr`.

`:%s/\(.\{80\}\)/\1\r/g`

will break all lines at 80 chars.

Comment: This saved my day while resurrecting an OpenSSL certificate. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

First, set textwidth to 5 with

```
:set tw=5
```

Then, press `gqap` to format a paragraph